# Question on Linear Alegbra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, diagonalization, trace

Let $A$ be $2 \times 2$ matrix with trace 2 and determinant -3. Let $T:M_2(\mathbb{R})\to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by$T(B)=AB$. Then How to show that $T$ is diagnalizable? Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: If the trace is 2 and determinant is negative 3, then the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 3$, which has distinct roots. Any matrix with distinct roots is diagonalizable.